# XHTML facebook like button

Tags: xhtml, facebook-like

I'm currently inlcuding a facebook like button like this

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
//]]></script>
...
<span class="fb-like"></span>
```

My problem:

[image: facebook like button]
            The like text is too wide. Usually you use the data-tag to determine the width

```
<span class="fb-like" data-width="150"></span>
```

This would cause the document to be invalid (the data-tag is not XHTML-valid).
Is there any way to set the width without breaking the XHTML validation?

```
<span class="fb-like" style="width:50px;"></span>
```

won't work cause the div inside the span class has a greater width.

Comment: Why don’t you just use the XHTML version of the Like button?

Comment: I can't see any XHTML version of the like button at the [developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)?

Comment: Click on “Get Code”, choose “XHTML” on top of the dialog.

Comment: There is no XHTML Button for me, only HTML5, XFBML, IFRAME, URL

Comment: Well OK it might be named XFBML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are going for, but I think is what you want:

```
<span class="fb-like" style="overflow: hidden; width: 50px;"></span>
```

Comment: sorry forgot to include width.